# Summing nested value if it exists

Tags: javascript

I have an array that looks like this:

```
const values = [
  {
    value: 2000,
    items: [
      {
        value: 300,
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

I want to sum the total of all of the values in `values.value`, and if a `values.items.value` exists I also want to include it in my sum.

```
values.reduce((total, obj) => obj.value + total, 0);
```

What would be the correct way to key into the nested array so it sums both the top and nested `value` key in my reduce function? The output I'd like is `2300` but right now I can only get one level deep, and it's outputting `2000`.

Comment: Will the nesting depth always be one or it can be of any depth ?

Comment: It will always be just two

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could nest your `reduce` approach to handle the inner array while ensuring that the key exists in the inner array objects.

```js
const values = [
  {
    value: 2000,
    items: [
      {
        value: 300,
      },
    ],
  },
];

const total = values.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  acc += obj.value;
  acc += obj.items.reduce((a, o) => 'value' in o ? o.value + a : a, 0);
  return acc;
}, 0);

console.log(total);
// 2300
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use reduce add value and check for `items` if it's there then add the value of items arrays as well

```js
const values = [{value: 2000,items: [{value: 300,},],},]


let op = values.reduce((op,{value,items}) => {
  op+= value
  if(items && items.length) {
    items.forEach(({value})=> op+=value )
  }
  return op
},0)

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 0):

I will add an inner `reduce()` to get the accumulated sum for the `items` array. Also, I will add some checks with `isNaN()` and `Array.isArray()` just for safety:

```js
const values = [
  {value: 2000, items: [{value: 300}]},
  {value: 3000},
  {value: 2000, items: [{value: 300}, {foo: 20}]},
  {nothing: "nothing"}
];

let res = values.reduce((acc, {value, items}) =>
{
    acc += isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    acc += Array.isArray(items) ?
           items.reduce((sum, {value}) => sum + (isNaN(value) ? 0 : value), 0) :
           0;
    return acc;
}, 0);

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate keys/values of the object and sum the a nested object and take the wanted key or zero as start value.

```js
function sum(object, key) {
    return Object.entries(object).reduce((s, [k, v]) => {
        if (v && typeof v === 'object') return s + sum(v, key);
        return s;
    }, key in object ? object[key] : 0);
}

const values = [{ value: 2000, items: [{ value: 300 }] }];

console.log(sum(values, 'value'));
```